# Where to get free WiFi access at JFK, landside and airside?

Tags: budget, wifi, jfk

In Terminal One, there is a hotspot, but it requires registration. In Terminal 7, (If I recall), British Airways have WiFi for their travellers.

**Where at JFK, can one get free Internet access, and in what conditions?**

Comment: @s.brody It's not of course, it's an important part of the question.  I recommend that you add it to the question.

Comment: Departure or arrival?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Paid**:
Free 30 Minutes of Wi-Fi [Source](http://nypost.com/2014/06/25/free-wi-fi-coming-to-jfk-laguardia-airports/)
Pay as you go: $4.95 per hour
Day Pass: Unlimited access for a 24-hour period, $7.95
Unlimited Access: Unlimited access for a month, $9.95 per month
Paid Wi-Fi available is some gates.

**Free (Work In Progress)**:
Terminal 4- Jetblue offers free Wi-Fi (sometimes)
Terminal 4- 
Terminal 5- Jetblue offers free Wi-Fi

Comment: Ok, so the paid options are available on all terminals. How are the hotspots named? And I assume the payment is done online via a credit card?

Comment: One I recall was Boingo Hotspot.

Answer (score 1):

If your laptop has a relatively good antenna, then you can stalk the outside of Delta Sky Club lounges and see if you can pick up their free internal wifi. There was a period when they were enforcing passwords / logins, but this is no longer the case apparently (I now have a mobile plan that allows sharing, so I no longer lounge-stalk).